# DOM Event listeners are not getting invoked

Tags: angular, dom, dom-events

We are working on an Open Source Chrome extension: [Digital Assistant Client](https://github.com/Digital-Assistant/Digital_Assistant_Client)

We attach our own click event listener to the Clickable DOM node during recording the sequence so that what user has clicked we will populate according to the click. There is an issue coming for some angular websites. The event listeners that are attached to the DOM node are not getting triggered. What should i do please let me know how i can make sure that event has been triggered even if the bubbling of the event is stopped.

I tried checking the event listeners from the developer tools and i do see the clickable node has the recording event listener.